# Package fontawesome5 Error: The requested icon COG was not found

Tags: errors, fontawesome5

```
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper,12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\section*{prepaper}
\begin{itemize}
  \item a
\end{itemize}
\section{\faIcon{cog}b}
\section{\faIcon{cogs}c}
\end{document}
```

I have an error:Package fontawesome5 Error: The requested icon COG was not found. \end{document}
but when I use

```
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper,12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}
\title{a}
\author{a}
\date{2021/03/16}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{prepaper}
\begin{itemize}
  \item a
\end{itemize}
\section{\faIcon{cog}b}
\section{\faIcon{cogs}c}
\end{document}
```

It can be compiled.

Comment: erhm, the latter example does not compile for me on TeXLive 2020. But it works fine if I use something else than `ctexart` (both cases), so my guess is not really `fontawesome` but rather the font setup in `ctexart`

Comment: it's a problem with \MakeUppercase probability？I was told

Comment: Could very very vel bee as it say COG in capitals. But that is not the error I get: `Critical Package ctex Error: CTeX fontset `fandol' is unavailable in current mode.`

Comment: I can confirm that I get the same error message as daleif for both examples below on TeX Live 2020.